# Primefaces menubar vertical separator

Tags: css, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.5. There is a vertical seperator in `p:toolbar` (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/toolbar.xhtml).

I want to use vertical seperator in `p:menubar`. When I use the `<p:separator />` tag in `p:menubar`, it makes a horizontal seperator.

How can i use vertical seperator in `p:menubar`?

Thanks.

Comment: what is this code? where is output?

Comment: you mean the code in the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it with next css:

```
.ui-menu .ui-separator { 
   background: #A8A8A8; 
   border: none; 
   width: 1px; 
   clear: none; 
   height: 22px; 
   margin: 4px 6px 0; 
   box-shadow: none; 
}
```

The key things are **width** and **clear**. Height, background color and margin you can adjust for your preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<p:spacer width="1" height="22" style="position: relative; bottom: -5px;background-color: #A8A8A8; margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px" />
```

[image]

Comment: This is a working solution, but I would remove the `height="22"` and add `style="height: 100% !important;"`

Comment: It is an option. But I chose to leave fixed, due to the adjustment `bottom: -5px`. That is, depending on the value of the `height`, you must change the value of the `bottom` to center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p:separator id="customSeparator" style="width:100%;height:1px" />
```

Comment: that creates a horizontal seperator, not vertical

Comment: Sorry!... what if you try setting style="width:1px; height:100%;"

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt work neither. it creates a 1px horizontal seperator, and rest of the menu elements goes under that seperator

Comment: Try this: style="width:1px; height:100%; float:left;"

Comment: Is your site online so that I can see the problem? Hard to help out like this.

Comment: @tylerdurden use style="width:10px; height:100%; clear: none;"

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer, but hope it helps someone.

With latest versions of primefaces (v10 current) .. For primefaces menubar vertical seperator, you can use

```css
<p:divider layout="vertical"/>
```

For those who are using lower versions & couldn't find anything ..
Use the trick - Show right border of submenu, it will work like vertical seperator.
Something LIKE

```
<p:menubar style="bgcolor: black;">
    
    <p:submenu label="Submenu1" icon="pi pi-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #c8c8c8;">
        <p:menuitem value="Menu01" action="#{bean.method01}" />
        <p:separator />
        <p:menuitem value="Menu02" action="#{bean.method02}" />
    </p:submenu>
    
    <p:submenu label="Submenu2" icon="pi pi-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #c8c8c8;">
        <p:menuitem value="Menu11" action="#{bean.method11}" />
        <p:separator />
        <p:menuitem value="Menu12" action="#{bean.method12}" />
        
    </p:submenu>
    
</p:menubar>
```

NOTE - I'm using `<p:separator />` for Horizontal seperation of menuitem.